# Indicator function for divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, divisibility, special-functions

Is there well known or common notation for an indicator-like function that tells if $a$ divides $b$? Something like the Kronecker delta, but for divisibility?

A function like:

$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}:\mathbb{Z}^2 \mapsto \{0,1\} \text{, where }
\mathcal{I}(a,b)=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } a\mid b\\
0, & \text{if } a \nmid b
\end{cases}
\end{align}$

Or is there a better way to think about this function?

Comment: We do have $\mathcal I(a,b)=1+\left\lfloor\frac ba\right\rfloor -\left\lceil\frac ba\right\rceil$, using the floor and ceiling functions, respectively. I don't think that's a better way, but it's a different way.

Comment: For positive $a,b; \ \delta _{\gcd (b,a),a}$